# XPages - onchange event on inputtext field lose click

Tags: xpages

I have a simple form with an onchange event on a field of type inputText.

Onchange event start when I click another object. Example the save button.

The code runs but the onchange click on the Save button is lost.

I enclose the sample code of a page that reproduces the problem.

Suggestions?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:div style="padding:20px;"></xp:div>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1" style="margin:20px;">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print('click');}]]></xp:this.action>
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert('click');]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup1" style="margin:20px;">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="val1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="val2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="val3"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print('onchange - radiobutton');}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:radioGroup>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" style="margin:20px;">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print('onchange - start');
    var millis = 10000;
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); } 
    while(curDate-date < millis);
    print('onchange - finish');}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>
    </xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `oninput` event instead of `onchange`. Just change the event attribute in the eventHandler. However,

1. It's not supported before IE9,
2. Every keystroke will trigger the event which could be bad for user-experience
3. In case of a partial refresh, when the refresh is over, the focus will be shifted to another component if it's not the first item in the form. Again, bad for UX.

You may also fire a CSJS code on `onkeyup` event to focus another component on the page. Therefore it will refresh the page. You may do this with `setTimeout()` function therefore, if the user does not press any keys for a moment, it will fire the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but I think that these solutions are not good for UX.

I think that only possible solutions are:
1 disable server onchange event and add refresh button
2 when possible use onchange client js event

Others suggestion?